# SQL fetch associated columns in aggregated results

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this little table

```
Insert into Temp (key1, key2, value1, value2) VALUES
(10, 100, 20, 200),
(11, 101, 19, 199),
(12, 102, 21, 202);
```

If I run

```
SELECT MAX(key1), MIN(key2) FROM Temp;
```

I get

```
12, 100
```

as expected.

I also want to return the values associated with those keys, something like

```
SELECT MAX(key1), value1-which-has-that-max-key, MIN(key2), value2-which-has-that-min-key FROM Temp;
```

which in this example should return

```
12, 21, 100, 200
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use subselects:

```
SELECT
    MAX(T1.key1) AS maxkey1,
    (SELECT value1 FROM Temp AS T2 WHERE T2.key1 = MAX(T1.key1)) AS value1,
    MIN(T1.key2) AS minkey2,
    (SELECT value2 FROM Temp AS T3 WHERE T3.key2 = MIN(T1.key2)) AS value2
FROM Temp T1
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f5bd/2)

Note that this will fail if you have more than one key with the same minimum/maximum value. If you might have this situation you may want to add an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` so select one of the rows rather than giving an error.

Comment: I'm concerned about efficiency. Won't each subselect perform an extra pass over the table?

Comment: It will not need to scan the table if you have the appropriate indexes. I assume that if you are concerned about efficiency then you have already learned about indexes added the appropriate indexes to your table, right? And are you using `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use two derived tables each of which would be returning the top-most row from an ordered row set. One would sort its row set in the descending order of `key1` and the other in the ascending order of `key2`. This is what I mean:

```
SELECT
  max.key1,
  max.value1,
  min.key2,
  min.value2
FROM
  (SELECT key1, value1 FROM Temp ORDER BY key1 DESC LIMIT 1) max,
  (SELECT key2, value2 FROM Temp ORDER BY key2  ASC LIMIT 1) min
;
```

A "live" demonstration can be found [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ca4c/1).

If there can (and actually happens to) be more than one row with the same maximum value of `key1` or the same minimum value of `key2`, this query will work, but, similarly to what Mark Byers said about his solution, I would suggest adding additional criteria to the ORDER BYs to make the results (more) predictable.